# ceph status fails due to "ERROR: missing keyring" error

Tags: juju, maas, ceph

I have deployed 3 ceph mon nodes using juju and maas. From juju status all ceph mon nodes are up and fine. but i did ssh into one of the ceph node and was just trying to get ceph status. and its giving me this error,

```
ubuntu@CS1:/home/ubuntu# sudo ceph status
2013-09-02 11:01:32.157892 7f8fc3d65780 -1 monclient(hunting): ERROR: missing keyring, cannot use cephx for authentication
2013-09-02 11:01:32.157928 7f8fc3d65780 -1 ceph_tool_common_init failed.
```

And then i discovered for any ceph command its giving me same error.

Before ceph deployment in .yaml file i had sepecifed $fsid and $monitor-secret values. So i think juju should take care of keyring, but looks like it doesn't. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like mistake from my side, while generating monitor secret, i didnt specified name parameter,  so i regenerated monitor secrete with that parameter like this,

```
sudo ceph-authtool /dev/stdout --name=mon. --gen-key
```

And redeployed ceph mon and OSDs, but this time i also took care of capital letters.That information was also helpful James.Thx !

Answer (score 5):

I think you are probably hitting this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/ceph/+bug/1218852

Right now the version of Ceph in 13.04 and the Ubuntu Cloud Archive for Grizzly can't deal with uppercase letters in hostnames.

Your hostname appears to be 'CS1'.

Comment: fwiw an update for ceph has been released which should fixup the capital hostname problem some folks have seen.